# Should [story-identification] Qs with correct answer be post-tagged with author's tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging, story-identification, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we tag story identification questions with the name of the author?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/should-we-tag-story-identification-questions-with-the-name-of-the-author)

@MajorStackings asked in chat:

> Quick question: Once a story identification question gets answered, should additional tags be added for future reference?