# Do we edit tags based on answers?

Tags: discussion, tags, story-identification

In particular, for a [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) question, do we add tags based on the accepted answer?

Comment: do you have an example of this being done, or what you'd like to see?

Comment: @phantom42:  I don't have a link,  but I mean, would we add the author or the work if the tag exists,  once the answer is known?

Comment: In that case, your suggestion is a dupe of the one Richard linked to. Unfortunately, we never came to a clear consensus in the issue. Feel free to bump it and maybe something can be better decided this time.

Answer (score 4):

Generally no, post-editing an *accepted* [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) question is discouraged since it doesn't show what the accepted answerer had to work with ;-)

**See also;**

- [Should we tag story identification questions with the name of the author?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/should-we-tag-story-identification-questions-with-the-name-of-the-author?rq=1)

---

The sole exception I can think of would be where the original tags were wildly inaccurate or selected in error by an inexperienced user.

For example, I recall an incident where I deleted the tag [short-story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-story) where the OP had put both [short-story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-story) AND [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel). Obviously it couldn't be both.

Comment: Now I wonder if I've boobed. See this edit: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/90356/revisions (although you did approve it, Richard)

Comment: @fruitbat - That's fine. The tags didn't match the description.