# What to do when a vague identification question is off-topic, but the answer is on-topic?

Tags: discussion

This question was put on hold for being off-topic: [Which anime are these images from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151083/which-anime-are-these-images-from) The question is a `story-identification` question with no details that make it on-topic, so putting it on hold was a solid decision.

However, the answer (which I wrote in a comment) is a video game with a fantasy setting. So the question as such is not on-topic, but the answer is kind of on-topic.

Can the question somehow be edited to be on-topic now that I know it could be? Can I rewrite it to make it seem like the person who asked knew it had a fantasy setting? Is that allowed?

Comment: (And because someone will ask: I did not know the answer myself, but consulted my wide array of friends knowledgeable in questionable genres.)

Comment: Just because I'm curious, what was the game called?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ _Senran Kagura: Estival Versus_: http://youtube.com/watch?v=Kghk7WRxa0Q

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ That video doesn't contain any fantasy elements, but that's where the images in the original question were from. The story does, though: http://senrankagura.wikia.com/wiki/Senran_Kagura:_Estival_Versus#Story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to **click the "reopen" button** (which shows up if youve got over 3000 rep and puts the question into the review queue) and **post a comment explaining that the story-id *is* on topic**, then wait for the community to reopen the question, allowing you to post an answer.

If you're the impatient sort, or lack sufficient rep to start the reopen process, you can always hurry things along by **posting a meta question** (like the one above) and/or **nipping into chat (where you'll invariably find higher rep users at all times of day) to cast around for a few upvotes** to get it reopened.

<s>You may wish to note that the question is currently on 4 votes to reopen and will likely be opened again within a few hours.</s>

Since the question has now been reopened, this is a pretty solid confirmation that the steps outlined above *do actually work*.

---

What you shouldn't do is edit the question to make it closer to the answer. [This post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/671/should-we-tag-solved-story-identification-questions-with-the-name-of-the-autho) relates to retroactively editing tags, but the principle is very much the same.

Comment: There's a "reopen" button? I can't find it. It says underneath the question that I should reword it to fit the rules if possible, which is why I asked specifically about editing. But if I shouldn't edit it, like you say (and which makes sense), how would it be reopened?

Comment: Ah. Looks like perhaps I would need 3000 reputation for that button to show up.

Comment: @tobiasvl  -  I cast the last reopen vote, enjoy!

Comment: @Gallifreyan Haha, thank you! Time to watch the rep roll in for this obscure softporn game.

Comment: I'll accept this answer (I also upvoted it, but seems someone else downvoted), but I have to admit I think it felt a bit complicated to have to go into chat and beg for reopen upvotes for a question like this. But if that's the solution for us low-rep plebs, than that's the solution, I guess!

Comment: @tobiasvl - The problem with poorly trafficked tags is that you sometimes need to "prime the pump" to get stuff reopened. Now if it had been a Star Trek or LOTR question, it would have had fifty views in the first hour, leading to a swift community consensus on its merits.

Comment: @tobiasvl - I suspect your rogue downvoter may have wanted to take me to task for not pointing out that you need 3000 rep to put something into the review queue. I've edited it now and hopefully they'll return in future to undownvote.

Comment: @Valorum Sounds likely. And like you say in your edit, yes, your procedure worked, so it's a good answer (which is why I accepted it). With my previous comment I meant exactly what you say: That the procedure itself leaves something to be desired for low-traffic tags like this. Your last paragraph about not editing questions to make them closer to the answer was what I was *really* wondering, anyway :) (Editing questions to fit answers is obviously wrong in principle, but this seemed like an edge case, especially when it was how the site told me to get it reopened.) So thanks!

Comment: We have a precedent for this: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117078/4918 What creature has spokes in its eyes, a beak, and strands of hair coming from the very tip of its triangular ears?