# Halo by Tom Maddox vs. Halo franchise

Tags: discussion, tags

As I had found out the title of the [book I was seeking](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195330/book-about-a-space-station-computer-keeping-an-engineer-alive) was *Halo*, I just ran a quick search for [halo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo) to see if there were other questions about this work by Tom Maddox... and found out that Halo is reserved for the *Halo* series of games and novels. Wouldn't it be more relevant to tag these later ones [halo-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo-series) to make [halo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo) free for the [tom-maddox](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tom-maddox) book, should questions about it arise?

Comment: Or [halo-game] or [halo-bungie]. (Not sure of the best way to disambiguate there.)

Comment: As the games are clearly more popular on the site the best way to tag, when needed, would be tag the book by Maddox as [halo-1991]

Answer (score 7):

We don't have the need yet. There are currently no questions about *Halo* by Tom Maddox: a search for [`is:q maddox halo`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+maddox+halo) yields 0 results.

We also don't retroactively tag [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) requests with tags for the correct work or author.

If and when we get a question about *Halo* by Tom Maddox, we can decide how to tag it, and whether to retag the current [halo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo) questions.

Comment: Related Meta conversation to the above: [Should we tag (solved) story identification questions with the name of the author / property?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/671/98028)